# What SignalR method is called when the connection is lost or is there a handler for connection state changes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket, signalr

I'm working on a .NET web app using SignalR with the hub class similar to the example class below:

```
public class ContosoChatHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        // Add your own code here.
        // For example: in a chat application, record the association between
        // the current connection ID and user name, and mark the user as online.
        // After the code in this method completes, the client is informed that
        // the connection is established; for example, in a JavaScript client,
        // the start().done callback is executed.
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        // Add your own code here.
        // For example: in a chat application, mark the user as offline, 
        // delete the association between the current connection id and user name.
        return base.OnDisconnected();
    }

    public override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        // Add your own code here.
        // For example: in a chat application, you might have marked the
        // user as offline after a period of inactivity; in that case 
        // mark the user as online again.
        return base.OnReconnected();
    }
}
```

More specific, my web app serves as hub for connecting tablets. when i close the app on the tablet it does not trigger instantly the OnDisconnected task, taking up to 20 seconds or more (server tries to reconnect with the client).

My question is, which method should I use in order to detect the connection loss as soon as it happens or, is there a connection state handler that triggers when the connection is lost?

In order to prevent the data loss (considering a tablet online when in fact it's not) I really need to handle the disconnecting event.

Any help is much appreciated!

Later edit:
I've also included the following lines in the Global.asax file

```
GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6);
GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
```

in the Application Start method. The values seem to be saved, as seen in debug and actually reduce the time by half, from 20-30 to 12-14 seconds, but it's still not  as close to 2-3 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You can detect the server disconnection from SignalR client:

```
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
alert('Server has disconnected');
});
```

This is the official documentation when each method called:

> **When OnConnected, OnDisconnected, and OnReconnected are called**
>
> Each time a browser navigates to a new page, a new connection has to
>   be established, which means SignalR will execute the OnDisconnected
>   method followed by the OnConnected method. SignalR always creates a
>   new connection ID when a new connection is established.
>
> The OnReconnected method is called when there has been a temporary
>   break in connectivity that SignalR can automatically recover from,
>   such as when a cable is temporarily disconnected and reconnected
>   before the connection times out. The OnDisconnected method is called
>   when the client is disconnected and SignalR can't automatically
>   reconnect, such as when a browser navigates to a new page. Therefore,
>   a possible sequence of events for a given client is OnConnected,
>   OnReconnected, OnDisconnected; or OnConnected, OnDisconnected. You
>   won't see the sequence OnConnected, OnDisconnected, OnReconnected for
>   a given connection.
>
> The OnDisconnected method doesn't get called in some scenarios, such
>   as when a server goes down or the App Domain gets recycled. When
>   another server comes on line or the App Domain completes its recycle,
>   some clients may be able to reconnect and fire the OnReconnected
>   event.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It takes around 20-30 seconds. I made some research and it seems that this time game appears due to SignalR trying to reconnect until finally triggering the OnDisconnected task.
What is the difference between OnDisconnected and OnDisconnectAsync?

Comment: The truth is that this function is old, now I have checked and I think it is deprecated, I edited my answer. 
What is your meaning of "connection is lost"?

Comment: First of all thanks for your insight. I've also edited my initial post. Hope it gives a more clear view regarding my issue.